# Listen and Refresh Commit Changes on Tig

Tags: git, tig

I'm using `:! git pull` command for pulling changes from a repo. But Tig doesn't refresh main view list when pulling changes. Is there anyway to listen and refresh commits on main view list at Tig automatically?

Answer (score 0):

From my mind I **think** it's possible after the `git pull` command to press a uppercase `L` and the complete tree will be reloaded.

Comment: If I press the `L` from keyboard it's saying: "Unknown key, press h for help". So, It doesn't work. Anyway, I'm currently using `Shift+R` for reloading commit list.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the `F5` key.

There are more situations where you might need to update the view (after committing, switching branch, ...).